# How to serialize an object that has a constantly updated collection

Tags: c#, serialization, collections

I have a cache service that holds multiple Price objects which are updated as new price deltas arrive, sometimes multiple times a second.
Each object holds it's various prices in a collection assigned to an ID. If someone subscribes to a particular price I need to serialize the latest price object into JSON each time a new price arrives in order to send it over RMQ.  The problem I am having is that in some cases I receive the following error message while serializing because a new price has arrived and updated the collection on the object during the serialization of the previous.

**"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."**

I've tried various ways of serializing the object (it needs to be as fast as possible) but I still get the same issue.

What would be the best and most efficient way of solving this so I can serialize even if the object changes.

The simplified objects are:

```
 //This is the collection on an object that holds the prices which are being updated
 public ConcurrentDictionary<Id, Prices> Asset{ get; set; } 

 //Class that holds the ever updating prices
 [Serializable] 
  public class Prices 
  {

      public Prices()
      {
          Prices1 = new List<PriceVolume>();
          Prices2 = new List<PriceVolume>();
       }
   }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: The simplest way I can imagine is to create a deep copy before serializing it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of serializing the actual object you pull from the concurrent dictionary you should create a deep copy of it and serialize the copy. unfortunately you will still have to put the code to get the copy inside a mutex. The ConcurrentDic is only protecting you from having an item changed or deleted while you are retrieving it, it does not protect the object from manipulation after you have retrieved your reference to it.

Comment: What's the point of creating a deep copy first if you have to lock the concurrent dictionary anyhow?

Comment: The dic only locks the object for the retrieve, its does not prevent it from being changed while you are serializing it. You will have to lock section either the entire pull and serialize or to keep the lock smaller just the section where pull and copy, either way the dictionary is not providing you any safety here.

Comment: I thought there might be a clever way of avoiding the deep copy and the serialize step however as you say it seems unavoidable the more I look into it. I'll have to still handle the object being updated during this process as well as you say.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could probably benefit from [`locking`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/lock) the element while you are serializing it.

Locking prevents other threads from modifying the element while you are inside the lock.

This will make the operations trying to change the prices wait until you are done serializing it to modify them.

```
[Serializable]
public class Prices
{
    public string Serialize()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            // logic for serilization here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The class interface will have to change too, because the ConcurrentDictionary is currently a public field.

Comment: That lock doesn't prevent other threads from changing things. It only prevents changes made by code that knows about and agrees to follow the lock convention. `lock` is a cooperative mutual exclusion device. If you want to use `lock` here, then all code that accesses the dictionary must also use the `lock`. All well and good, except that would eliminate any benefit to using `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but how about looking into Serialization Callbacks (some refer to this as Serialization Hooks) and Implementing the **ISerializable** Interface. You seem to need more fine-grained control over the serialization of your object. Have a look at this link:

[Custom Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx)

Look at the following

- **OnDeserializingAttribute** (Before deserialization)
- **OnDeserializedAttribute**  (After deserialization)
- **OnSerializingAttribute**   (Before serialization)
- **OnSerializedAttribute**    (After serialization)

Also have a look at this link:

[Version Tolerant Serialization](http://[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.110).aspx][2])

You can consider if the object warrants the use of the **OptionalFieldAttribute** or **NonSerializedAttribute** on certain fields to control if they need to be serialized or optionally serialized. Just be wary of the use of the **NonSerializedAttribute**. Have a look at the best practices mentioned in the article (reproduced here for reference):

> To ensure proper versioning behavior, follow these rules when modifying a type from version to version:
>
> - Never remove a serialized field
> - Never apply the **NonSerializedAttribute** attribute to a field if the attribute was not applied to the field in the previous version
> - Never change the name or the type of a serialized field
> - When adding a new serialized field, apply the **OptionalFieldAttribute** attribute
> - When removing a **NonSerializedAttribute** attribute from a field (that was not serializable in a previous version), apply the **OptionalFieldAttribute** attribute
> - For all optional fields, set meaningful defaults using the serialization callbacks unless 0 or null as defaults are acceptable
>
> To ensure that a type will be compatible with future serialization engines, follow these guidelines:
>
> - Always set the VersionAdded property on the **OptionalFieldAttribute** attribute correctly
> - Avoid branched versioning